# Type specification for if/else braces in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm beginner in dart language and Flutter SDK.
I try to make clear code by using analysis_option.yml from official flutter project.

I get stuck on this warning :
[image]

It seems that adding `<dynamic>` before the brace removes the warning, but it makes no sense for me.

Someone can explain why this is necessary ? And how a scope can return a type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you put `=> <dynamic>` at the beginning of the anonymous function:

```dart
//                          vv vvvvvvvvv
.then((dynamic currentUser) => <dynamic> {
```

By doing this, instead of an anonymous function with a body, you have declared a lambda function that returns a `Set<dynamic>`. Moving on:

```dart
  if (currentUser == null)
    <dynamic> {...}
```

Dart is now thinking you are defining elements of a `Set`. Dart also supports collection conditionals, so your `if/else` are being interpreted as conditionals in a `Set` literal.

*(If you don't know what collection conditionals are, it's similar to Python compositions and basically means that `[ 1, if (false) 2 else 3 ]` will produce the list `[1, 3]`.)*

And so because you also provided a body for the if statement but didn't have a semicolon at the end of its single statement, Dart is once again thinking you are specifying a `Set`. Because the Dart auto-formatter is so helpful, it is helpfully suggesting that you add an explicit type annotation to your `Set` literal that you've "defined" under the else statement.

```dart
else 
  {...}

// Dart formatter: "It looks like you are trying to create 
//                  a `Set<dynamic>`. Do you need some help 
//                  with that?"
```

Essentially, the root cause is because of the `=>`. In Dart, you only use `=>` if you are defining a lambda, a.k.a. a single line anonymous function. (Compared to Javascript, which uses `=>` for all of its anonymous functions, lambda or not. Isn't being a multi-lingual programmer the greatest?)

If you take out the `=> <dynamic>` it should fix all the "errors".

Comment: I wasn't expecting something so interesting ! So, if I want to 'fix' this, I must use ```=> <void>``` at beginning of the lamda function, right ? Because if I remove the return type, I get the same warning on the function brace
Edit: no ok, I got it, if I remove the ```=>```, my function became an anonymous function, and then don't return and doesn't have to provide a return type

Comment: @ErwanDaniel Dart uses type inference to set the return type of anonymous functions. As far as I know, there's no way to explicitly define what the return type should be. If you want to explicitly set the return type, you have to create a named function.